# Call method1 before calling other methods in class

Tags: c#, .net, class, oop

I have built a **class library** with the following class:

```
public class Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {
    }

    public void Method1()
    {
        //user should call this method before Method2
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        //user should call Method1 before calling this method
    }
}
```

How can I prevent the user from calling **Method2** before calling **Method1**?
Thanks

Comment: Don't put anything users shouldn't use in the public interface.

Comment: user need to call both of them

Comment: Then you need a re-design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have a flag set when the first method is called:

```
public class Class1
{
    private bool hasCalledMethod1;

    public Class1()
    {
    }

    public void Method1()
    {
        //user should call this method before Methode2

        hasCalledMethod1 = true;
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        if (!hasCalledMethod1)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Must call Method1 before calling Method2");
        }

        //user should call Methode1 before calling this method
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't need a flag or exception this will throw exception during Run Time.
i need to prevent him from calling it while coding.
maybe use attribute or some things like that

Comment: @asem you can't enforce this at compile time. Use documentation and exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just force this by calling `Method1()` inside `Method2()` like below

```
public void Method2()
{
       Method1();
      //Do rest of the work here     
}
```

So, whenever user calls `Method2()` directly without calling `Method1()` it will make sure that `Method1()` has already been processed before processing of `Method2()` body starts.